# Pandas посчитать количество элементов равное заданному значению

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Дан df:

```
    a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 'AAAA - dkfkdnfk'},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 'AAAA - dkijonfk'},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 'AAAnA - dijodnfk'},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 'AAAA - kjldkfkdnfk'},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 'AAAA - dkfkdnfk'},
    
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 'BBB - dkfkdnfk'},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 'BBB - dkfikoikdnfk'},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 'BBBk - dkkfkdnfk'},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 'BBB - dkfkdnfk'},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 'BBB - dkfkdnfk'}])
```

Нужно сгруппировав по `id`, далее у `b == 2` посчитать сколько у них значений `d` (d.split(' - ')[0]) совпадает со значением `d` (d.split(' - ')[0]) из `b == 1` того же `id`. Результат записать в столбец k. Должно получиться:

```
            pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 'AAAA - dkfkdnfk', 'k': '2'},
                          {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 'AAAA - dkijonfk', 'k': '2'},
                          {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 'AAAnA - dijodnfk', 'k': '2'},
                          {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 'AAAA - kjldkfkdnfk', 'k': '2'},
                          {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 'AAAA - dkfkdnfk', 'k': '2'},
        
                          {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 'BBB - dkfkdnfk', 'k': '3'},
                          {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 'BBB - dkfikoikdnfk', 'k': '3'},
                          {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 'BBBk - dkkfkdnfk', 'k': '3'},
                          {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 'BBB - dkfkdnfk', 'k': '3'},
                          {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 'BBB - dkfkdnfk', 'k': '3'}])
```

P.S. У каждого `id` будет только одна строка с `b == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
a[["tmp"]] = a["d"].str.split("-").str[0]
a["k"] = a.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: (x["b"]==2)&(x["tmp"] == x["tmp"].iloc[0])).groupby("id").transform(sum).to_list()
a.drop("tmp", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

a:

```
   id  b                   d  k
0   1  1     AAAA - dkfkdnfk  2
1   1  2     AAAA - dkijonfk  2
2   1  2    AAAnA - dijodnfk  2
3   1  2  AAAA - kjldkfkdnfk  2
4   1  4     AAAA - dkfkdnfk  2
5   2  1      BBB - dkfkdnfk  3
6   2  2  BBB - dkfikoikdnfk  3
7   2  2    BBBk - dkkfkdnfk  3
8   2  2      BBB - dkfkdnfk  3
9   2  2      BBB - dkfkdnfk  3
```

Но вообще, хотелось бы видеть уже ваши попытки что-то сделать. Иначе создается впечатление, что мы делаем за вас вашу работу.

Comment: Спасибо, извините, что создается такое впечатление, в следующий раз буду и свой код в вопросе упоминать, но впечатление, что я тупо без всяких попыток прошу помощи - ошибочно.

Comment: здравствуйте, вы случайно не знаете как можно решить вот такую проблему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1256558/362663